# Creating unique files in another directory

Tags: c#

Currently i am taking in multiple .txt files from a directory i have specified (sourceDirectory). I am generating new .csv files with the same name as the .txt files - one .csv file for each .txt file.

However i want to generate these new files in another directory which i have specified (directoryPath). If i run my program once it creates these files in the initial directory, however if i run my program again it now generates the files in the destination directory.

The following is my code where i complete the above:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string sourceDirectory = @"C:directoryWhereTXTFilesAre";

        var txtFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceDirectory, "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        foreach (string currentFile in txtFiles)
        {
            readFile(currentFile);
        }

        string directoryPath = @"C:\destinationForCSVFiles"; 
    }
```

I then create the new .csv files name based on the original .txt file like this:

```
static FileStream CreateFileWithUniqueName(string folder, string fileName, int maxAttempts = 1024)
        {
            var fileBase = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName);
            var ext = Path.GetExtension(fileName);

            // build hash set of filenames for performance
            var files = new HashSet<string> (Directory.GetFiles(folder));

            for (var index = 0; index < maxAttempts; index++)
            {
                // first try with the original filename, else try incrementally adding an index
                var name = (index == 0)
                    ? fileName
                    : String.Format("{0} ({1}){2}", fileBase, index, ext);

                // check if exists
                var fullPath = Path.Combine(folder, name);
                string CSVfileName = Path.ChangeExtension(fullPath, ".csv");
                if (files.Contains(CSVfileName))
                    continue;

                // try to create the file
                try
                {
                    return new FileStream(CSVfileName, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write);
                }
                catch (DirectoryNotFoundException) { throw; }
                catch (DriveNotFoundException) { throw; }
                catch (IOException)
                {

                }
           }
```

I don't see why it's creating the .csv files initially in the same directory that the .txt files are in and then second time i run my code it creates them in the directoryPath.

Desired output: sourceDirectory left as it is with only .txt files and directoryPath to hold the .csv files.

The only other place i call CreateFileWithUniqueName is within my readFile method, the code is below:

```
     using (var stream = CreateFileWithUniqueName(@"C:destinationFilePath", currentFile))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Created \"" + stream.Name + "\"");
                newFileName = stream.Name;
                Globals.CleanedFileName = newFileName;
    }
```

Comment: But you haven't show the code that calls _CreateFileWithUniqueName_ Please add it

Comment: @Steve i have edited the question with the code.

Comment: Can you elaborate slightly? Do you mean the first time i try with the fileName within the for loop?

Comment: No, wrong comment, deleted

Comment: @Steve Okay, it must be something around that though because i can't see why anything else may affect it

Comment: I can't find anything really wrong in the _CreateFileWithUniqueName_ so perhaps the problem is before the first call. I suggest to use the debugger to put a breakpoint on the first line of the method and check what values are passed to the method

Comment: @Steve if i put a breakpoint on the first line inside CreateFileWithUniqueName and have a look at string folder being passed in its the correct destination folder and string file is a .txt file from the source folder.. Which confuses me more because if i put the breakpoint at the end of the CreateFileWithUniqueName method it has created all the .csv files in the source folder..

Comment: did you forgot a slash after drive in literal string of sourcepath ?

Comment: @user3800527 no thats just an example, in my code the source directory is a full functional file path.

Comment: Let's try this. Don't create the file inside CreateFileWithUniqueName, but just return the string with the calculated new name. In the calling code write with a messageBox or a Console.WriteLine the string returned and check it

Comment: @Steve if i insert a breakpoint at the bottom of the CreateFileWithUniqueName and hover over var fullPath it holds the file path of the source directory with a .txt file and then string CVSfileName holds the source directory with .csv file

Comment: @Steve ** var fullPath = Path.Combine(folder, name);**  'folder' holds the correct destination folder however 'name' seems to hold the full file path incl source directory. Could this be resetting or overwriting 'folder's value?

Comment: That's explains a lot, are you passing the full filename of the source file?

Comment: @Steve Yea - when i'm doing path.combine 'name' holds the full file path from the source directory. that would suggest the error is where I am instanating var name?

Comment: Yep, it is documented on Path.Combine. It resets your path to the last absolute path found in the strings passed as arguments to Path.Combine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are passing the full filename of the source file. This confuses the Path.Combine inside the CreateFileWithUniqueFilename because you are falling in this subtle remarks found on the documentation of [Path.Combine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991142(v=vs.110).aspx)

> paths should be an array of the parts of the path to combine. If the
>   one of the subsequent paths is an absolute path, then the combine
>   operation resets starting with that absolute path, discarding all
>   previous combined paths.

You can fix it easily with

```
 using (var stream = CreateFileWithUniqueName(@"C:\destinationFilePath",  
                                        Path.GetFileName(currentFile)))
 {
      Console.WriteLine("Created \"" + stream.Name + "\"");
      newFileName = stream.Name;
      Globals.CleanedFileName = newFileName;
}
```

Or better extract the filename without path inside the CreateFileWithUniqueName

```
static FileStream CreateFileWithUniqueName(string folder, string fileName, int maxAttempts = 1024)
{
    var fileBase = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
    fileBase = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileBase);
    var ext = Path.GetExtension(fileBase);
```

also, you should build your CSVfileName using the cleaned filename

```
    var name = (index == 0)
        ? String.Format("{0}{1}", fileBase, ext);
        : String.Format("{0} ({1}){2}", fileBase, index, ext);
    var fullPath = Path.Combine(folder, name);
    string CSVfileName = Path.ChangeExtension(fullPath, ".csv");
    if (files.Contains(CSVfileName))
        continue;
```

Comment: Defining fileBase twice? did you mean to define something else?

Comment: copy/paste is difficult without VS that babysit your code.

Comment: No problem, I am glad to help people like you that work hard to understand their own code See you again on SO